# Table normalization

Tags: database, normalization, database-table

Can you help me to normalize a table. The exercise say: "Find the functional dependencies (FD) and normalize the table" (i guess this means to put it in 3NF):

```
A |B |C |D
------------
a1|b1|c1|d1

a2|b1|c1|d1

a1|b1|c2|d1 

a5|b2|c5|d1 

a6|b1|c7|d2 

a3|b1|c1|d4

a1|b5|c4|d3
```

I didn't find any FD. The simple types of FD are:

```
{A} -> {B}

{A} -> {C}

...

{B} -> {A}

...

{D} -> {A}

{D} -> {B}

{D} -> {C}
```

Altogether 12. I refer from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and looked at this kb article from MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only FD that *might* exist there is **C -> B**.
That is, all the other ones do not hold...

However, FD-s are normally **inferred from domain knowledge**, not from some data :)

In case you want to study more about these, I would recommend an on-line (free) DB course, held by a professor at Stanford University: https://www.coursera.org/course/db.

No offence, but this looks like homework :)

Comment: You are correct, C-> B is the FD because each C value is associated with precisely one B value. I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @user2873588, you can close the question if you believe that it has been answered :)